# How to clear cache using Selenium webdriver Java?

Tags: java, selenium

I want to clear cache for my Selenium project. We have written code for deleting cookies. But we want to get the cache cleared to get our things work. This is for Google Chrome and language used is Java.

Answer (score 0):

To clean cache you can clear local storage

```
 LocalStorage session = ((WebStorage) driver).getLocalStorage();
 session.clear();
```

It will remove your local storage and clear all chache

Comment: getting Failed to read the 'localStorage' property from 'Window' error using this

Comment: Answer updated. Can you please try now

Comment: same error happening with this also